# How do I make a Laravel 5.1 ACL work with a client and admin panel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, acl

My situation:
Using Laravel 5.1, I want to use it's built in ACL features.
Challenge:
My website has a Admin and a Client side to it. On top of that, the database structure for each is very different and the Control Panel for Admin and Client is very different.

How do I go about implementing ACL with this?

**Note** - I have subfolders for each part of the website (one folder for client side, one folder for admin, one folder for front-end pages).

Is this even possible to build using Laravel's built-in ACL system? or should I make my own in my situation? Thank you.

Comment: I am going to suggest that you make your own or use one of the available already built ones. You might want to look at catalyst sentinel, or the authorization module in orchestra.

Comment: @delatbabel - ok, thank you!